# Struts 1.x - aggregate one bean in another one without CDI

Tags: java, struts-1

I am new to Struts. I am curious how can I do this in Struts 1.x without CDI/Spring:

```
public class MyBean {

    private OtherBean ob;

    public MyBean(){
        ob = (OtherBean) StrutsContext.getInstance()...;
    }

}
```

In usuall CDI in JSF I can simply @Inject:

```
public class MyBean {

    @Inject
    private OtherBean ob;
    //getter and setter;
}
```

I need OtherBean's method to be executed within MyBean method.

Comment: There is no such feature in native Struts 1, it is too old. It is so old that Apache itself has declared it end of life and pretends it no longer exists, you or your employer should take the hint!

Comment: Yea.. That's the problem where theres an app from.. 2006 and migrating to another technology would take quite long time.. Thanks :)

Comment: The documentation of Struts 1 is hidden away here: http://archive.apache.org/dist/struts/documentation/ . Good luck!

Comment: Do what specifically? Under what container (which may provide its own DI mechanism)? I mean, you know the class; where do you keep the instance?